# nodejs make execSync don't output stdout and stderr in console

Tags: node.js, linux

I use following code to determine port is listened or not

```
export var portIsListened = (port: number) => {
  try {
    return execSync(`netstat -tlnp | grep ${port}`).toString() != ""
  } catch (e) {
    return false
  }
}
```

when use `portIsListened(6000)`, I expect determine port is not listened and only return false, but in console always raise following err, how to hide it

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
```